# Add a new list item to a Key value database

Tags: json, list, key-value, key-value-store, nosql

I'm working on a game, and for each user, I have a list called PlaySessions which stores all data related to a certain play session.  For example:

```
{"PlaySessions":[{"playsession Date":"12-12-2014","playsession points":"120"},
{"playsession Date":"14-12-2014","playsession points":"200"}]
}
```

I want to add a new play session to this list, so it becomes:

```
{"PlaySessions":[{"playsession Date":"12-12-2014","playsession points":"120"},
{"playsession Date":"14-12-2014","playsession points":"200"},
{"playsession Date":"15-12-2014","playsession points":"300"}]
}
```

Will I have to download the entire list, add the element manually on my client game and then resend the list so it overwrites the old one?
If there is another, cleaner way of doing this then thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm not clear which nosql you are using, but this just looks like an `insert` to me. Like `db.PlaySessions.insert({"playsession Date":"15-12-2014","playsession points":"300"})`

Comment: I'm using a game backend service, so I don't have entire control over my database.
do you think I should stop using this service and have my own server with my own database